# Is there an Oracle SQL tool that builds insert statements from a result set?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, resultset

Is there an Oracle SQL tool that builds insert statements from a result set?  We are currently only allowed to use a tool called SQL Station.  I'd like to either suggest a tool, like Rapid SQL or CrazySQuirrell, or build my own re-usable chunk of sql.

Comment: In my current position we use Oracle SQL Developer.  It does have the ability to create insert statements from a result set as noted by edwards and suggested by dpbradley.

Comment: Right-click on the table, select EXPORT, choose Save As WORKSHEET, click NEXT, add a WHERE clause, click GO, click OK, click NEXT, click FINISH.  You can get rid of the Create DDL statements and copy out the Insert statements.  while not as pretty as other tools, it does work.

Comment: Just adding another [helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1650969/707414) for somewhat similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution, which is what I'm using now.  Thanks for all of the help.
It turns out we can use SQL+ too.  For some reason I can't run it in SQL Station.

COPY FROM userid/password@from_DB TO userid/password>@to_DB INSERT toDB_tablename USING SELECT * FROM fromDB_tablename where ....;

commit;

Answer (score 4):

Where is this result set coming from?  If you mean that you want to execute a SELECT, then insert the resulting data into another table, you can do that in a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (columnA, columnB)
  SELECT columnA, columnB
    FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm grabbing the data from one database and moving it to another.

Comment: You could create a database link and do the query against the remote table.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?  SQL Station is old and crappy.  However it is all we are allowed to use.

Comment: Well, probably you'd need to ask your DBA to do it, but you can try it.  I don't know SQL Station, but I assume it allows you to execute any SQL.

If both databases are Oracle:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm#i2061505

Comment: If the other database is not Oracle, start here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/ds_concepts.htm#sthref3857

Answer (score 3):

PL/SQL Developer will do this as well.  I've used both PL/SQL Developer as well as Oracle's SQL Developer, and in my opinion PL/SQL Developer has a smoother and more consistent interface.  Not sure about SQL Developer, but PL/SQL Dev. also lets you export result sets as CSV,XML, and HTML.

It also behaves OK under WINE if you're running Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you want command line tools, the free cx_OracleTools will do this, and some other nice things as well.

http://cx-oracletools.sourceforge.net/

- CompileSource - execute statements in a file, checking for errors
- CopyData - copy data from one table or view to another
- DbDebugger - allows simple debugging of PL/SQL
- DescribeObject - describe objects as SQL statements for recreation
- DescribeSchema - describe multiple objects as SQL statements for recreation
- DumpCSV - dump the results of a select statement as comma separated values
- DumpData - dump the results of a select statement as insert statements
- ExportColumn - dump the data from a column into a file
- ExportData - dump the data from a database into a portable dump file
- ExportObjects - describe object as SQL statements for recreation in files
- ExportXML - export data from a table into a simple XML file
- GeneratePatch - generate SQL script to go from one set of objects to another
- GenerateView - generate a view statement for a table
- ImportColumn - import the contents of a file into a column in the database
- ImportData - import the data dumped with ExportData
- ImportXML - import data from an XML file (such as those created by ExportXML)
- RebuildTable - generate SQL script to rebuild the table
- RecompileSource - recompile all invalid objects in the database

Answer (score 1):

Yes look at Oracle sql developer.Its free can be downloaded from otn.oracle.com

Comment: Unfortunately we are not allowed to use this.  I'm stuck with trying to come up with a long hand solution.  When I have time...

Comment: That's ok...it's a buggy turd IMHO anyways.  {-o)

Comment: Thanks edwards.  Now that I'm working somewhere with more modern tools, I've been using this and it is working fine.  See my comments in the original post for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, using string contatenation works great for smaller statements you want to build:

```
Select
    'Insert Into MyOtherTableTable Values(''' || MyMainTableColumn1 || ''' and ''' || MyMainTableColumn2 || ''')'
From MyMainTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the result set of the query, you will get a pop up. select export data and insert. it will ask you for the location to save the file in which insert statements are generated. give file name and the path to save it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but It could be helpfull for somebody.
If you go to the table, you can "export" the data. The second step is "Specify Data" where you can add some filters.
This only works for a table data.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle SQL-Developer type and execute as script (F5):

```
select /*insert*/ 
  * from dual;
```

output:

```
 Insert into "dual" (DUMMY) values ('X');
```

you can try also /*csv*/" or /*html*/

source: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/

```
SELECT /*csv*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*xml*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*html*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*delimited*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*insert*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*loader*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*fixed*/ * FROM scott.emp;
SELECT /*text*/ * FROM scott.emp;
```