# How to take backup as insert queries from oracle select statement inside UNIX batch job?

Tags: oracle, unix

I wrote a UNIX batch job which updates a table with some "where" conditions. Before updating those records, i need to take the backup (insert statements) of the records that is returned with the "where conditions" and store it in ".dat" file. Could you please help on this???

Comment: This seems an extremely ropey way of doing a backup. How do you propose to rollback an `update` with an `insert`? If you don't trust your batch job [take a proper backup](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/high-availability/rman.html).

Comment: You can use spool command to export data 

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve043.htm#SQPUG126

Comment: APC, before updating ill use the same conditions with a select query and want to take insert scripts from it

Comment: and how do you envision using the 'insert' script?  You've stated what you "want" to do - your preferred technical solution to some business problem, but you have not stated why you reject a different approach.  If you simply want a way of reverting the table back to it's "pre update" state, I'd simply create a backup table - 'create mytable_bkup as select * from mytable',

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to create a backup of the table would be to use a create table statement using the where condition(s) of your update statement. For example, let's take a sample update statement:

```
UPDATE sometable
SET field1 = 'value'
WHERE company = 'Oracle'
```

This update would update the `field1` column of every row where the company name is Oracle. You could create a backup of `sometable` by issuing the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable_backup AS (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE company = 'Oracle');
```

This will create a table called `sometable_backup` that will contain all of the rows that match the where clause of the update.

You can then use Data Pump or another utility to create an export .dat file of that specific table. You can use that .dat file to import into other databases.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But i want to know whether there is any possible way to take the insert scripts via UNIX batch job????

Comment: Yes you can. However, why do you need to store those insert statements as a .dat file? That is why there were a number of comments asking you why you would do it that way. You could easily use a program like SQL Developer to generate the inserts using a hint in the query (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173540/generate-insert-statements-for-each-entry-in-a-table) or you could just run the select and export the data set from SQL Developer as insert (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26159765/979604) but the .dat file part is confusing - typically an insert script would be a .sql file.